# How can I retrieve the local path of an image after it being loaded from the web?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

Is it possible to get the local path of an image?
Let say I have the following piece of code:

```
<img src="http://myserver/myimg.png" id="myimg"/>
```

The file should be downloaded somewhere locally. 
Is it possible to get its path in JavaScript? A string that would look like "C:\Users\blabla".

Comment: The browser's cache will know where the local copy is, but there is no JS access to that data. It'd be a major security risk if it were allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **No**.

JavaScript cannot access a users file system under any circumstances (this would be a security nightmare).

Answer (score 1):

> The file should be downloaded somewhere locally.

It could be held only in RAM.

> Is it possible to get its path in JavaScript?

No. Even if the browser has cached it to disk, JavaScript doesn't have access to any information about that cache.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not, you can't access the filesystem from withhin javascript.
Why would you like to do that?